# Append onClick handler to a substring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pulling data through from graphql and generating an excerpt on my Gatsby site.

```
const str = productDescription.substring(0, 150) + '...';
```

Then outputting it in the component like so:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: str }} />
```

I want to append an onClick handler to the end of the excerpt

I've attempted making a new const and adding it to the end of the 'str' const.

```
const more = <span onClick={ () => setModal(true) }>More</span>
const str = productDescription.substring(0, 150) + '...' + more;
```

All that's returned is `[object object]`

Not sure what to try next, any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

That because you concatenate `string` with `JSX` element.

One solution is to group them in a `fragment` tag to be as an element.

```
const more = <span onClick={ () => setModal(true) }>More</span>
const str = <> {  productDescription.substring(0, 150) } ... { more } } </>
```